# I want Dojo NumberTextBox accepts and shows only decimal number with comma not with point

Tags: dojo

For example

- if I type 33.86 I want NumberTextBox to show error message
- if I type 33,86 I want NumberTextBox to accept

I tried

```
var number = new NumberTextBox({
    required: true,
    constraints: {min:0, max:100, pattern: "#,##%"}, "number"});
number.startup();
```

This shows number as I want (after typing, when I click out of NumberTextBox) but accept only decimal with point not with comma.

Comment: do you want to set the number format for the whole page OR only for the particular widget? which country format do you want to consider for formatting the number? Please provide relevant/more information

Comment: I want to set number format only for particular NumberTextBox in my form.

Comment: I want to use Serbian format for formating the number, or other country where comma is used with decimal numbers like,Germany, Portugal, Bulgaria, Romania..

Comment: If you need additional information please let me know. I am dojo beginner

Comment: can you try the following constraints `constraints:{locale:'de', min:0, max:100, pattern: "#,##%"}, "number"}`. `de` stands for germany.

Comment: when i use the constraints above numbertextbox accepts decimal number with comma but when i remove focus from numbertextbox it show number with point. Now it is different situation than it was before setting locale to de, when numbertextbox accepted number with point but showed number with comma